# Trying to get property of non-object on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I got an error message on my laravel app as below:

```
production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Trying to get property of non-object' in /home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html/app/controllers/distanceController.php:1470
Stack trace:
```

the error refer to this code:

```
$distance = distanceGeoPoints($loc1min->latitude, $loc1min->longitude, $latitude, $longitude);
```

Please advise what is the problem and how to solve it.

Comment: are you using googleMap api in Laravel right?

Comment: I'd say that `$loc1min` is not an object. What does `dd($loc1min)` show?

Comment: just below the line you have provided add `var_dump( get_class( $loc1min ) );` and check if the classname is correct ?

Comment: do something like this {{$distance[$loc1min]}} in view.

Comment: $loc1min = WalkLocation::where('request_id', $request->id)->where('created_at', '<=', $one_minut_old_time)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();

Comment: yes, i am using googlemap api

Answer (score 0):

```
$loc1min = WalkLocation::where('request_id', $request->id)->where('created_at', '<=', $one_minut_old_time)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

This returns null in your code on some reason. It seems, database doesn't have the record, matching your conditions.

Comment: @Elo If it does, why does your query returns null? Call `toSql()` on it instead of `first()` and debug the query.